# Create, validate and upload data in mvvm with fragments

Tags: android, mvvm

First of all, I have a model what I want to upload to my server. It has lot of enum and text fields so i need to separate it. I need some fragments or views to collect data from user and validate them. How can I implement this function in mvvm design pattern? Is there any good example? Should I create viewModels to every fragments/views or only the activity? Thank you!

Comment: Provide your snippet of code. So that we can help you.

Comment: Please provide some code to us

Comment: I havent code yet. :(